# None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied on koin in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, koin

I am using koin **v3.2.0** in my jetpack compose application. I am getting weird issue on my `viewModelOf`. I imported correctly as well from the [sample project](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin-compose/blob/main/sample-compose/src/main/java/org/koin/sample/androidx/compose/di/appModule.kt).

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'

    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha14'

    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.0'
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'

    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.17.0"

    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:$lottieVersion"

    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-compose:$koin_version"

}
```

**AppModule.kt**

```
package com.vivek.sportsresult.di

import org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.dsl.viewModelOf
import org.koin.dsl.module

val appModule = module {
    viewModelOf(::MainActivityViewModel)
}
```

**MainActivityViewModel.kt**

```
package com.vivek.sportsresult.viewmodel

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {
}
```

**Image Error**

[image]

Error is too big I am short description.

```
one of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
Module.viewModelOf(() → TypeVariable(R))   where R = TypeVariable(R) for    inline fun <reified R : ViewModel> Module.viewModelOf(crossinline constructor: () → R): KoinDefinition<R> /* = Pair<Module, InstanceFactory<R>> */ defined in org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.dsl
```

Can somone guide me please. My Project on [Github](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult) Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your  AppModule.kt import this:

```
import com.vivek.sportsresult.viewmodel.MainActivityViewModel
```

Your new AppModule.kt:

```
package com.vivek.sportsresult.di

import com.vivek.sportsresult.viewmodel.MainActivityViewModel
import org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.dsl.viewModelOf
import org.koin.dsl.module

val appModule = module {
    viewModelOf(::MainActivityViewModel)
}
```